# How to use previous element in vector in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I'm taking a digital signal processing course which requires me to use Matlab. I'm still very much a beginner, so I'm sorry if this is something very basic but I don't know how to google for this.

I'm supposed to check for linearity. I have a couple of vectors made with `randn(1,100)` and I'm supposed to use them to check if

```
F{a·x1 [n]+b·x2 [n]} = a·F{x1 [n]}+b·F{x2 [n]}
```

When for example `F{x[n]} = x[n] + 2` adding to the vectors is easy.

One of the problems is `F{x[n]} = ¼ (x[n]+2·x[n-1]+x[n-2])` where I need to access the previous 2 elements in the vector. How can I do this? There's also one where `F{x[n]} = n·x[n]`. Here also I need the specific index of the element.

**EDIT:** Thanks for your answers. I didn't really know how to approach this so I couldn't think up a sample code to try. I just figured out that I should create shifted vectors for the n-1 and n-2 values and use a separate index vector for the n*x[n] thing. So I was approaching this whole issue from the wrong angle. This probably isn't the most elegant solution but it works. Sorry for wasting anyone's time.

Comment: Read the [*documentation*](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html)

Comment: I realise that you're a beginner, but you've made this question a bit unclear by using code formatting for stuff which isn't at all MATLAB syntax. At the most basic level, access array elements using parentheses not square brackets, and curly braces are only for accessing cell arrays not calling functions. I would start by defining how you would do this *on paper*, then clearly show us what you're trying to do mathematically and what code you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

It is straightforward.

```
>> x=[1,2,3,4]
>> x(2-1)
ans =
     1
```

Make sure you don't go beyond the limit (i.e. x(0) yields an error since index must start from one).

Answer (score 0):

```
x = randn(1,1000);
res = f(x,5);

function res = f(x,n)
    if ((n < 3) || (n > numel(x))
        error('Be careful with index overflows!');
    end

    res = 0.25 * (x(n) + (2 * x(n - 1)) + x(n - 2));
end
```

In Matlab, a numeric array can be indexed with a value between `1` and `length` (for the latter you can also use `end` so you don't need to know the length of the array in order to retrieve it's last value). Example:

```
>> x = [1 4 7 3 2 9]

x =

     1     4     7     3     2     9

>> x(1)

ans =

     1

>> x(2)

ans =

     4

>> x(5-2) % the index is 3 here

ans =

     7

>> x(6)

ans =

     9

>> x(end)

ans =

     9
```

[Matrix Indexing In Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html)